# Tar command throwing errors when attempting to create an archive using the date command

Tags: date, command-line, archive, tar

I use the `tar` command a lot, very familiar with it. However, I tried creating an archive using the date command to name the archive file, and it throws an error to the effect that it can't open the file, which is strange because I'm not trying to open the file but create it.

Here's a copy of the directory, the code, and the error:

```
@MDG /media/VideoCam/Test $ ll
total 468
drwxr-xr-x 3 neo neo   4096 Sep  5 09:55 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 neo neo 466944 Sep  4 21:54 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo neo     45 Sep  5 08:52 1.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  5 08:41 1.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  4 19:32 2.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  5 08:41 2.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  4 19:32 3.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  4 19:32 4.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  5 08:41 4.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  4 19:32 5.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  5 08:41 5.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  4 19:32 6.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  5 08:41 6.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  4 19:32 7.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  5 08:41 7.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  4 19:32 8.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 neo neo      0 Sep  5 08:41 8.mp4
drwxr-xr-x 2 neo neo   4096 Sep  4 19:30 Archive/
neo@MDG /media/VideoCam/Test $ sudo tar -zcvf "archive.$(date '+%D').tar.gz" *.jpg
tar (child): archive.09/05/17.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
6.jpg
7.jpg
8.jpg
neo@MDG /media/VideoCam/Test $
```

I've tried many different concatenations, with and without quotes, switching up the order of the command options (zcvf), etc. If I leave out the date command and just give it a name, e.g. `archive.tar.gz`, it executes perfectly, but introducing the date command causes the error.  I've also tried setting the date command as a variable with a similar result.

Comment: Fix formatting please.

Comment: `/` is not allowed in filenames.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the error message, you see

```
tar (child): archive.09/05/17.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

This indicates that it is trying to create the file `archive.09/05/17.tar.gz`. That is, `17.tar.gz` in the directory `05`, in the directory `archive.09`.

If this is what you actually want, which I doubt, you need to create the directory outside `tar` with something like

```
mkdir -p archive.09/05
```

If you don’t want subdirectories, you cannot use the `/` character in the filename. Try a different format for the `date` command; one common option is `+%F` because it generates filenames which would still be in the right order if sorted as text.

Comment: Wow, thanks to everyone who answered this question so quickly!  Although I've been using Linux a long while, I am def a noob when it comes to even the simplest coding/scripting.  The answer seems so obvious but it eluded me completely.  Also, per @Cyrus, I will check out the editing-help.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you read the `date` man page and check the formatting options.

As it's been suggested by others the issue is with the format of `date` output

```
$ date '+%D'
09/05/17
```

You can't create a file with slashes in the name because of Unix typical behavior. You should instead try something like

```
$ date '+%m-%d-%Y'
09-05-2017
```

That in case you want to preserve the same formatting as `%D`.

Answer (score 0):

The date is pritning out slashes and it's treating it as folder path. Use dashes.